# Why does MacVim crash on Zoom

Tags: macvim

If I open Macvim, everything works fine, unless I zoom in (using Cmd+"+").

If I do that, then I get a strange black boarder around the added bit of the window and the whole thing freezes.

This is what I see:

[image]
(except, bizarrely, it isn't, because I *see* a black boarder, the mac screenshot shows a light gray one, and the image uploaded to SE mysteriously makes it white, which suggests there's something wrong with me)

...and there is a 40 second video of the problem here: https://youtu.be/cjKWRGLSWTk, which, thankfully, shows the same black border I see. Thank you YouTube.

This appears to be part of a few linked bugs on MacVim, I have quite a lot of trouble with the display not refreshing if I've changed the zoom level while the app is already full-screen and that's quite frustrating.

Some useful information.  I'm on High Sierra 10.13.6. and I get the same error with /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim -u NONE -U NONE.  My custom vimrc is here: https://github.com/joereddington/dotvimdirectory

```
Josephs-Mini:.vim josephreddington$ defaults read org.vim.MacVim | grep 'MM\|SU'.
    MMAutosaveColumns = 155;
    MMAutosaveRows = 61;
    MMCurrentPreferencePane = General;
    MMLastWindowClosedBehavior = 2;
    MMOpenInCurrentWindow = 1;
    MMTopLeftPoint = "{375, 980}";
    MMUseCGLayerAlways = 1;
    SUEnableAutomaticChecks = 0;
    SUHasLaunchedBefore = 1;
    SUSendProfileInfo = 0;
Josephs-Mini:.vim josephreddington$
```

Comment: I've reported as an issue on the GitHub here, https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/875